# Google Contacts enabled for Google Apps, but Google disagrees

Tags: google-workspace, google-contacts

I've been using Google Apps for my personal domain for some time, using it for email and the calendar. A couple of hours ago, I activated Google Contacts in the domain dashboard. It is now listed as activated for my domain.

If I try to log in on the URL given in the dashboar, `https://www.google.com/contacts/a/mydomain.tld?hl=en`, I see the following error:

> **Contacts has not been enabled by the administrator of the domain @mydomain.tld.**
>
> You can sign into another account to use Contacts.
>
> If you are the Google Apps administrator, please read these articles to learn more about [controlling user access to Google Apps services](http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?answer=182426&hl=en&ctx=ch_b%2F0%2FServiceNotAllowed&p=contacts) and [turning services on/off for certain users](http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?answer=182442&hl=en&ctx=ch_b%2F0%2FServiceNotAllowed&p=contacts).

I've tried to log in using an @gmail.com account at google.com/contacts and then changing account to my Google Apps account. This results in an infinite HTTP redirect cycle.

What could I have missed?

Answer (score 2):

Turns out I just had to wait another few hours. 6 h after activating Contacts, it's working.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your Control Panel-> Organization, Users tab -> Services -> find Contacts and enable it.

Comment: Are you asking how to do it or are you offering a solution?